# What does it mean to "hold the legacy"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In the song 347aidan - Memories! he sings

> Breakin' apart, but I gotta hold my legacy

I know the word hold and legacy. But what does it mean to "hold the legacy"?

Comment: Hold "To maintain or keep to a position or state"  my legacy.  It seems fairly literally, if not a normal expression, it's just a lyric.

Comment: On the other hand, "hold something" can mean to delay or omit, as in "Hold my calls" or "A club sandwich, hold the mayonnaise." "Hold my legacy" isn't a common phrase; "hold on to my legacy" would be more usual.

Answer (score -1):

"Hold the legacy" means that the legacy the is intact and stable and possessed by some individual.

Comment: "Intact" is one word. This looks like opinon without supporting quotes.